# tkinter tkcalendar DateEntry inside class, did not display today's date, DateEntry outside class display today's date

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkcalendar

DateEntrys which are **inside** the class, **did not display today's date**, where as DateEntry which are **outside** the class **displays today's date**.

But DateEntrys which are **inside** the class, **printing today's date** correctly.

[image]

```
# import tk modules
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # get the system screen width and height
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        
        # application window width and height
        window_width = 430
        window_height = 115

        # display the window in center of the screen
        x = (screen_width - window_width) / 2    
        y = (screen_height - window_height) / 2

        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (window_width, window_height, x, y))

        # Make the window non resizable
        self.resizable(False,False)

        select_from_date = tk.StringVar()
        select_to_date = tk.StringVar() 

        dte_from_date=DateEntry(self,textvariable=select_from_date,date_pattern='dd-mm-yyyy').place(x=10,y=20)
        dte_to_date=DateEntry(self,textvariable=select_to_date,date_pattern='dd-mm-yyyy',).place(x=150,y=20)

        # print today's date correctly, but in the DateEntry, it is empty
        print(select_from_date.get())
        print(select_to_date.get())

        btn_generate = tk.Button(self, text='Generate').place(x = 10,y = 70)
        btn_settings = tk.Button(self, text='Settings').place(x = 290,y = 70)

def main():
    win = MainWindow()

    select_date = tk.StringVar()
    dte_date=DateEntry(win,textvariable=select_date,date_pattern='dd-mm-yyyy').place(x=290,y=20)

    win.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You did not keep a reference to the StringVars holding the values of the two DateEntries in the class, so they were garbage-collected at the end of the `__init__()` method - leaving the widgets with nowhere to store their value.  The StringVar for the third widget is in a global variable, so continues to exist.

Comment: @jasonharper `select_date` inside `main()` is also a local variable, but `mainloop()` keeps it in scope until closing the root window.

Comment: Thanks to jasonharper, acw1668. I understood the issue.
Is there any way to keep both select_from_date, select_to_date as global variable? I put both variables above class, but I got error "RuntimeError: Too early to create variable: no default root window"

Comment: You can change the two variables to *instance variables*: `self.select_from_date` and `self.select_to_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment, `select_from_date` and `select_to_date` are local variables inside `__init__()`, so they will be garbage collected after exiting `__init__()` function.

Simply change them to *instance variables*, `self.select_from_date` and `self.select_to_date`, to avoid garbage collection:

```py
class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # get the system screen width and height
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

        # application window width and height
        window_width = 430
        window_height = 115

        # display the window in center of the screen
        x = (screen_width - window_width) / 2
        y = (screen_height - window_height) / 2

        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (window_width, window_height, x, y))

        # Make the window non resizable
        self.resizable(False,False)

        # use instance variables instead of local variables
        self.select_from_date = tk.StringVar()
        self.select_to_date = tk.StringVar()

        DateEntry(self,textvariable=self.select_from_date,date_pattern='dd-mm-yyyy').place(x=10,y=20)
        DateEntry(self,textvariable=self.select_to_date,date_pattern='dd-mm-yyyy',).place(x=150,y=20)

        # print today's date correctly, but in the DateEntry, it is empty
        print(self.select_from_date.get())
        print(self.select_to_date.get())

        tk.Button(self, text='Generate').place(x = 10,y = 70)
        tk.Button(self, text='Settings').place(x = 290,y = 70)
```

Comment: thanks a lot acw1668. as per you suggestion, i changed local variables into instance variables. it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

> tkinter tkcalendar DateEntry inside class, did not display today's
> date, DateEntry outside class display today's date

Move those two `DateEntry` to `main()` function and comment out both prints.

Snippet:

```
def main():
    win = MainWindow()
    select_from_date = tk.StringVar()
    select_to_date = tk.StringVar() 

    select_date = tk.StringVar()
    dte_date=DateEntry(win,textvariable=select_date,date_pattern='dd-mm-yyyy').place(x=290,y=20)
    dte_from_date=DateEntry(win,textvariable=select_from_date,date_pattern='dd-mm-yyyy').place(x=10,y=20)
    dte_to_date=DateEntry(win,textvariable=select_to_date,date_pattern='dd-mm-yyyy',).place(x=150,y=20)

    win.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks toyota Supra. I modified code with extra function PlaceWidget and pass two variables as parameters as below. It is working fine.

```
# import tk modules
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

select_from_date = tk.StringVar()
select_to_date = tk.StringVar()
    
class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # get the system screen width and height
        screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
        
        # application window width and height
        window_width = 430
        window_height = 115

        # display the window in center of the screen
        x = (screen_width - window_width) / 2    
        y = (screen_height - window_height) / 2

        self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (window_width, window_height, x, y))

        # Make the window non resizable
        self.resizable(False,False)

    def PlaceWidget(self,select_from_date,select_to_date):     
    
        dte_from_date=DateEntry(self,textvariable=select_from_date,date_pattern='dd-mm-yyyy').place(x=10,y=20)
        dte_to_date=DateEntry(self,textvariable=select_to_date,date_pattern='dd-mm-yyyy',).place(x=150,y=20)        

        btn_generate = tk.Button(self, text='Generate').place(x = 10,y = 70)
        btn_settings = tk.Button(self, text='Settings').place(x = 290,y = 70)
        
def main():
    win = MainWindow()
    select_from_date = tk.StringVar()
    select_to_date = tk.StringVar()
    
    win.PlaceWidget(select_from_date,select_to_date)

    print(select_from_date.get(),select_to_date.get())
    
    select_date = tk.StringVar()
    dte_date=DateEntry(win,textvariable=select_date,date_pattern='dd-mm-yyyy').place(x=290,y=20)
        
    win.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```